# meteor: Use template to add some HTML by an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I need to create some HTML on an event.  Right now I do it by using JQuery.

```
Template.example.onRendered(function() {
    paper.on({
        'cell:mouseover': function(cellView, event){
            // create HTML construction
            $('<div/>', { id: 'toolbar' })
                .attr('data-id', cellId)
                .addClass(type)
                .css({
                    width: size.width + 'px',
                    top: pos.y + 'px',
                    left: pos.x + 'px'  
                })
                .appendTo('#canvas');
            // and so on...
    });
});
```

But as I'm using meteor I think it would be much smarter to use templates - in case the HTML I want to use will get more complex.

So how can I add a template to the DOM fired by an event function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use spacebars `{{#if myHelper}}` if it is a single html block. You add a reactive variable flag to your page (at the start of your js file) using the [reactive dict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) or [reactive var](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) package and you set it to true in your event. The helper `myHelper` will return it and trigger the display of your template.
2. if you need to generate as many html blocks as you receive your event, you can use `Blaze.render()` or `Blaze.renderWithData()` to attach the generated template to a DOM node. Example with a template named `GeneratedTemplate` attached to a DOM node with id `your_dom_node`:

   ```
   Blaze.renderWithData(Template.GeneratedTemplate, 
       {
        "arg1":"something", 
        "arg2": "whatever"
        }, 
        $("#your_dom_node")[0]
        );
   ```

Comment: I Need to create multiple elements. So I will give 2. a try

Comment: Does it append or replace the target?

Answer (score -1):

> So how can I add a template to the DOM fired by an event function?

Let's say we use the 'submit' event in a form. You can proceed like this:

```
Template.body.events({
   "submit .classname-of-my-btn": function(event){}
)};
```